# Killing parent process only, not both child and parent in bash

Tags: bash, kill, kill-process

I'm trying to kill process by name. It's supposed to kill children processes first then the parent later but I only get parent killed. Help needed please. EDIT: *SOLVED*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try it this way:

```
PID=$(ps -aef | grep `whoami` | grep $argument | grep -v grep | grep -v $$ | awk '{print $2}'
for x in ${PID[@]}; do
  CPID=$(ps -aef | grep `whoami` | grep $PID | grep -v grep | grep -v $$ | awk '{print $3}'
  for y in ${CPID[@]}; do 
    kill $y
  done
  kill $x
done
```